# How can I remove all other ids from this map object in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this function which recibes an item id from an array, and i map it to set a selected state to show that i have clicked that item.

```
const onSelect = React.useCallback(
        id => {
            const newSelected = new Map(selected);
            newSelected.set(id, !selected.get(id));
            setSelected(newSelected);
        },
        [selected],
    );
```

This is my state condition:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(new Map());
```

I want to only have 1 item selected at the same time, so if I click an item the others have to be set to false in state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you clone `selected`, map it and generate new entries with a toggled value if the key equals the `id`, and `false` if not:

```
const onSelect = React.useCallback(
  id => {
      const newSelected = new Map(selected.map(([key, value]) => [key, key === id ? !value : false]));
      setSelected(newSelected);
  },
  [selected],
);
```

In addition, in this case `useCallback` have almost no effect. Since `selected` changes oftenly, `useCallback` can't use the memoized function, and a new function is generated. To solve that, pass a function to `useState`, and remove `selected` from the dependencies array.

```
const onSelect = React.useCallback(
  id => setSelected(sel => new Map(sel.map(([key, value]) => [key, key === id ? !value : false])),
  []
);
```

Comment: It looks like the original functionality of the code snippet is to toggle the selected state if the currently selected item is selected - it doesn't look like this solution retains that functionality.

Comment: I get an error that im using side effects on the function, an that i shold use useEffect instead, its working properly, but how can i remove that message?

Comment: Have you tried the 2nd snippet? None of this is related to useEffect. Paste the error message, and relevant code. You might want to start a new question.